# Query the list of CITY names starting with vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, or u) from STATION. Your result cannot contain duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE CITY LIKE '[AEOIU]%';
```

Why this query is not working?

Comment: Please share some data and what output you are getting which leads to you think it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another ways:

```
SELECT * from STATION where FIND_IN_SET(left(CITY,1),'A,E,I,O,U')>0;
```

And

```
select distinct CITY from STATION where substring(CITY,1,1) in
('A','E','I','O','U');
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want regex like functionality, you should use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[AEOIU]';
```

Note that `REGEXP` by default is not case sensitive, so the pattern `^[AEIOU]` should pick up on cities starting with any vowel letter, having any case.

Also note that `DISTINCT` is not a function, hence the other change I made to your query.

If you wanted to do this without using `REGEXP` or `LIKE`, you could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE LOWER(LEFT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Comment: It can conatin both lower case and upper case

Comment: @rishav Both of my answers cover both lowercase and uppercase.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Distinct City From Station Where City LIKE 'a%' OR City LIKE 'e%' OR City LIKE 'i%' OR City LIKE 'o%' OR City LIKE 'u%';
```

On MySql

Answer (score 0):

select distinct CITY from STATION where left(CITY,1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u','A','E','I','O','U');

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
select distinct city
from station
where lower(left(city, 1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
order by city;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city 
  from station
 where city regexp '^[a,e,i,o,u]'
```

This worked for MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE city REGEXP '^[AEIOU]';
```

Hence Regular Expression is not case sensitive we can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT city 
FROM station 
WHERE city REGEXP '^[aeiou]';
```

Answer (score 0):

select distinct CITY from STATION where CITY like '%a' or CITY like '%e' or CITY like '%i' or CITY like '%o' or CITY like '%u' order by CITY;

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).